# Como usar funções extensivas no Javascript

Tags: javascript, funções, programação-funcional, extension-method

Em Javascript os tipos primitivos possuem funções nativas, como um objeto do tipo `Number` possui uma função `toString()`:

```
(1).toString(); // "1"
```

E um array possui um `includes()`:

```
[1, 3, 4].includes(1); // true
[1, 3, 4].includes(10); // false
```

Eu gostaria de poder criar um método nativo para arrays que me retorna `true` se este contém pelo menos um número impar e `false` caso este possua apenas números pares:

```
[8, 2, 4].hasOdd(); // true 
[1, 2, 4].hasOdd(); // false
```

Existe alguma maneira de eu criar um método que serve para determinado tipo de objeto em Javascript, como as [funções extensivas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) em Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### O que você está procurando é o `prototype`:

Todos os objetos javascript possuem métodos ineteres do seu prototype, então caso você queira usufluir de funções extensivas, podes fazer algo assim:

```
String.prototype.hello = function() {
    return `Hello, ${this}`;
}
```

Utilizando então da seguinte maneira:

```
"World".hello(); // "Hello, World"
```

Assim como  você pode modificar o prototype de `String`, você tem a liberdade de fazer o mesmo com o prototype do `Array`:

```
Array.prototype.plusOne = function() { 
    return this.map((e) => e + 1);
}
```

Utilizando da seguite maneira:

```
[10, 3, 5].plusOne(); // [11, 4, 6]
```

#### A resolução do problema:

Se sua ideia é criar um método nativo para arrays que me retorna `true` se este contém pelo menos um número impar e `false` caso este possua apenas números pares, você pode fazer assim:

```
Array.prototype.hasOdd = function() {
    return this.every((e) => e % 2 === 0);
}
```

Utilizando da seguite maneira:

```
[2, 2, 2].hasOdd(); // false
[1, 2, 2].hasOdd(); // true
```

#### Você deveria utilizar funções extensivas com prototype?

Depende, a [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp) não recomenda que você modifique os prototypes de objetos nativos do Javascript, você na teoria deveria apenas modificar prototypes dos seus objetos.

Como você está adicionando um novo método e não sobrescrevendo um antigo, creio que não existe problema, exemplo: Você não deve sobreescrever o método `toString()` do prototype de `Number`, isso pode criar efeitos colaterais no seu código.

> Only modify your own prototypes. Never modify the prototypes of standard JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 1):

Nos primórdios do desenvolvimento Web esta era uma prática comum, ([PrototypeJS](http://prototypejs.org/) e [Sugar.js](https://sugarjs.com/)) são bons exemplos.

O problema é manter a compatibilidade e interoperabilidade desses tipo de biblioteca, pois facilmente pode haver colisões.
Outro problema implícito, é algo que assombra o jQuery até hoje, não saber que aquele método não é nativo, para os mais desavisados pode tentar reproduzir esses comportamentos em outros projetos, e falhar miseravelmente.